# intrinsic and extrinsic parameters from 2D Homography

Tags: matlab, extrinsic-parameters

I have a single image . I have (e.g., 15 ) 2d projected points(x[pixel],y[pixel]) and corresponding  (X,Y,Z)(m). All points lying on the same plane.

3D points are transformed to 2D

Xtrans=X./Z;
Ytrans=Y./Z;
Ztrans=0;

Now I have computed 2d homography(H3*3=[...];) following the normalised direct linear transformation algorithm given by Hartley and Zisserman.

I want to get intransic and extransic parameters.
I could not find any link, code which solve this issue. Could some one guide me.
regards

Comment: could you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Specifically, be more clear on several things: what the projection is to and from, why you have 3d points and 2d points, what you mean by intrinsic and extrinsic parameters, and what specifically you're trying to solve?  Maybe find a link that is doing something similar to what you want and post it.

Comment: Check this link for better understanding the process. If you like it and you think you are looking for something like this, I can lead you to some code clues, but it is better that  you try yourself.
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/2736/1473